# How to reduce capturing time in raspberry pi camera?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am working on a program on raspberry pi b+ model, my program needs to capture images from a raspberry pi camera attached i used this code to capture images:

```
cmd='raspistill -o '+filename+' -t 10 -ex auto -awb auto -w 800 -h 600 '
pid=subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

when i tested this code the time for running just these two lines of code was about 1 second and this is way too much time

my question: is there any way to reduce time of capturing images, or is there any other features that can be added to the code to reduce the time of capturing ?

Comment: Are you saving them as .jpg?

Comment: @User404 yes i do save them as jpg

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the preview with `-n` (`--nopreview`) parameter may reduce the time.

```
cmd='raspistill -o '+filename+' -t 10 -n -ex auto -awb auto -w 800 -h 600 '
pid=subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

If writing to the SD card is the bottleneck (should not be, as they usually are fast enough), maybe saving the file to a [in-memory](http://www.zdnet.com/article/raspberry-pi-extending-the-life-of-the-sd-card/) filesystem would speed up taking the picture. You can sync the files to the sd card at some point later (e.g. cronjob with `rsync`).